# Google Map API How to set new option

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I never used Google API before and have no idea what API version i am currently using. I am using

```
var myOptions = {
                zoom: settings.zoomLevel,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(orig_lat, orig_lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.mapDiv),myOptions);
```

Added `height : 200` in `myOptions`
but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `map`'s div sizes by using CSS styles and whenever your `map`'s div changes its sizes, explicitly trigger '`resize`' event on Google Maps component.

About `'resize'` event:

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Answer (score 0):

You can specify map container dimensions in your css styles or by inline css styles.

Comment: yeah it works this way but if i change the width and height dynamically on the page the map does't resize